# same slug for different sub category in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I have a eCommerce website , and i want same slug for different sub category.
For Example:

1. First i create **men** **parent** category in product .And its **slug** is **men** and its **url** is **website_url/men**
2. Then i create **shirt** **sub** category. His **parent** is **men** and its **slug** is **shirt** and **URL** of this **website_url/men/shirt**
3. After that i create second **women** **parent** category. And its **slug** is **men** and its **url** is **website_url/women**
4. Then i create **shirt** **sub** category. His **parent** is **women** and its **slug** is **shirt-women** and **URL** of this **website_url/men/shirt-women**

But i need sub category url  like :

```
        For men shirt=  website_url/men/shirt
        For women shirt=  website_url/women/shirt
```

Comment: Is this WooCommerce?

Comment: yes i'm using  WooCommerce

Comment: You should have a base shop slug it's not recommended that you remove it. 
  Removing /product/, /product-category/, or /shop/ from the URLs is not advisable due to the way WordPress resolves its URLs. It uses the product-category (or any other text for that matter) base of an URL to detect that it is an URL leading to a product category.

There are SEO plugins that allow you to remove this base, but that can lead to a number of problems with performance and duplicate URLs. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

Answer (score 0):

How to add the category and product that means you have to develop the product section as per plugin or manually??

After I will give you the solution for same...

Comment: i'm using WooCommerce  plugin And i'm adding category  in product section